# Create variants of templated class with different initialization

Tags: c++, c++17

I am creating multiple different types of encoders where the main difference is the different data structures used to initialize the class. My header is something like this

```
struct tagTypeInfo {
        uint16_t start;
        uint16_t last;
        uint16_t count;
        std::string name;
        rdwrT rdwr;
};

template <typename T>
class encodedTag
{
public:
    encodedTag(vector<tagTypeInfo> tagInfo_) : tagInfo(tagInfo_)
    {
        int start = 0;
        for(auto & tag : tagInfo)
        {
            tag.start = start;
            tag.last = start + tag.count - 1;
            start = start + tag.count;
        }
    }

    uint16_t encode(uint16_t tag, T tagType)
    {
        assert(tag<tagInfo[tagType].count)
        return( tagInfo[tagType].start + tag );
    }
    std::tuple<uint16_t, T> decode(uint16_t encodedTag)
    {
        int type = 0;
        uint16_t tag;
        // simple linear search as there are only a few entries
        for (auto it = begin(tagInfo); it != end(tagInfo); it++)
        {
            if (encodedTag >= it->start && encodedTag < it->last )
            {
                // tag is in the range
                return {encodedTag - it->start , (T)type};
            }
            type++;
        }
        assert(false);    
        return {0,(T)0};
    }
    std::string getName(T tagType) {return(tagInfo[tagType].name);}
    rdwrT getRdwr(T tagType) {return(tagInfo[tagType].rdwr);}
private:
    std::vector<tagTypeInfo> tagInfo;
};

extern std::vector<tagTypeInfo> rdTag;
extern std::vector<tagTypeInfo> wrTag;

//using rdTagEncode = encodedTag<rdTagT>(rdTag) <-- error
```

The cpp file contains:

```
std::vector<tagTypeInfo> rdTag {
        {0, 0, NUM_HOSTRDTAG,        "HostRdTag",    RDWR_RD},
        {0, 0, NUM_SYSRDTAG,         "SysRdTag",     RDWR_RD},
        {0, 0, NUM_GCRDTAG,          "GCRdTag",      RDWR_RD}
    };

std::vector<tagTypeInfo> wrTag {
        {0, 0, NUM_HOSTWRTAG,        "HostWrTag",    RDWR_WR},
        {0, 0, NUM_SYSWRTAG,         "SysWrTag",     RDWR_WR},
        {0, 0, NUM_GCWRTAG,          "GCWrTag",      RDWR_WR}
    };
```

My goal is to be able to just declare an encoder in the code elsewhere with
`rdTagEncode myEncode;`
However I cant seem to figure out the right syntax to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: provide a default constructor? (dispatch based on type or just use a derived class)

Comment: Why is this a template? The only argument it makes sense for is `tagTypeInfo`. And what is `rdTagT`?

Comment: Also, `encodedTag<rdTagT>(rdTag)` is an expression, not a type. It is very unclear what this is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: @appleapple Let me lookup dispatch based on type

Comment: @molbdnilo This is an enum type that is the template param

Comment: @molbdnilo I can create an encoder in my code with: `encodedTag<rdTagT> myEncoder(rdTag);` I was hoping to find a way to not have to specify all that. It relies on  the vector rdTag having global scope which is undesireable

Comment: @appleapple dispatch based on type will not work as everything then needs to be part of the base template. Being able to provide a vector externally is helpful. Let me look at derived class

Comment: Ok, the derived class is the best solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a derived class was the best solution. Thanks for the suggestion @appleapple

```
class encodedRdTag : public encodedTag<rdTagTypeT>
{
    public:
    encodedRdTag() : encodedTag({
        {0, 0, NUM_HOSTRDTAG,        "HostRdTag",    RDWR_RD},
        {0, 0, NUM_SYSRDTAG,         "SysRdTag",     RDWR_RD},
        {0, 0, NUM_GCRDTAG,          "GCRdTag",      RDWR_RD}
    }) {};
};

class encodedWrTag : public encodedTag<wrTagTypeT>
{
    public:
    encodedWrTag() : encodedTag({
        {0, 0, NUM_HOSTRDTAG,        "HostRdTag",    RDWR_RD},
        {0, 0, NUM_SYSRDTAG,         "SysRdTag",     RDWR_RD},
        {0, 0, NUM_GCRDTAG,          "GCRdTag",      RDWR_RD}
    }) {};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here is the "dispatch based on type" method which I mentioned in comment above.

---

NOTE: this code doesn't work in original question as the `rdTag` and `wrTag` are same type thus independent of the class template `T`, but according to your own answer this may be actually what happends.

---

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct tagTypeInfo{};

struct rdTagTypeT{};
struct wrTagTypeT{};

std::vector<tagTypeInfo> get_default_info(rdTagTypeT); // return wrTag
std::vector<tagTypeInfo> get_default_info(wrTagTypeT); // return wdTag

template <typename T>
struct encodedTag
{
    encodedTag():encodedTag(get_default_info(T{})){}
    encodedTag(std::vector<tagTypeInfo> tagInfo) : tagInfo(tagInfo){};
    std::vector<tagTypeInfo> tagInfo;
};

using encodedRdTag = encodedTag<rdTagTypeT>;
using encodedWrTag = encodedTag<wrTagTypeT>;

void foo(){
    encodedRdTag rd;
    encodedWrTag rw;
}
```

Comment: I assume this line `using encodedWrTag = encodedTag<rdTagTypeT>;` was meant to be wrTagTypeT

Comment: @AndyTomlin true, fixed.